# Don't know why can't get data-id with jquery. It's always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get data-id with jquery. But with no success.
My jsp with data-id:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-track" data-id="${track.id}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
```

And my js:

```
var TracksController = function(){

};

TracksController.prototype.deleteTrack = function (el) {

    var id = $(el).attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/tracks/delete',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data){



        }
    })

};

TracksController.prototype.init = function () {

    var that = this;

    $('#delete-track').on('click', function () {
        that.deleteTrack();
        return false;
    });

};

$(function(){
    var tracksController = new TracksController();
    tracksController.init();
});
```

Thought that it had to work but... Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$(el).data("id")` it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `that.deleteTrack()` without any arguments, but deleteTrack expects an element.

`var id = $(el).attr("data-id");` fails because `el` is undefined

A fiddle for demo purposes: https://jsfiddle.net/kjb6ug9c/2/

Comment: @dannyjolie Tried your example but I can't work out how to make it work on my case. I am new in js. Could you please tell me how to make my example work?

Comment: @Dexa Ok, inside the click handler change `that.deleteTrack();` to `that.deleteTrack(this);`. It is really important that you try to understand why the change is necessary though :) Updated fiddle that looks more like your code: https://jsfiddle.net/kjb6ug9c/3/

Comment: @dannyjolie You are a total genius! It works! And thanks for an axamples.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$(el).data("id")`. The data function allows you to store/fetch the data stored in elements. You can read more about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: While this is true, it has nothing to do with the error in the code with `el` being undefined that causes the problem in the first place.